# Running distributed Tensorflow on Google Cloud ML engine ClusterSpec

Tags: tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am trying to run a large distributed tensorflow model on Google Cloud's ML engine and am having trouble understanding what should go on [tf.train.ClusterSpec](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).

When you run a job on Google Cloud you can select the [scale tier](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/training-overview) from BASIC, STANDARD_1, PREMIUM_1, BASIC_GPU or CUSTOM, each giving you access to different types of clusters. However, I can't find the name/addresses of the machines in these clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the documentation and sample [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/trainer-considerations). You should set ClusterSpec using the environment variable TF_CONFIG; e.g.

```
  tf_config = os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG')

  # If TF_CONFIG is not available run local
  if not tf_config:
    return run('', True, *args, **kwargs)

  tf_config_json = json.loads(tf_config)
  cluster = tf_config_json.get('cluster')
  ...
  cluster_spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.